# Vertx Jackson JSON Lib Conflict

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, vert.x, apache-phoenix

I m using vertx 3.3.3, and Phoenix 4.4.2 both of them comes with Jackson JSON Lib 2.6, for my use case i need the       `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES set to True`

But this feature is only available starting from the 2.8 version, so I have added this lib as a dependency in my vertx project .

my dependencies in my builde.gradle looks like this :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-core:3.2.1'
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.2.1'
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:3.2.1"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:3.2.1"
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-auth-jwt:3.2.1'
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-jdbc-client:3.2.1'
    compile group: 'de.svenkubiak', name: 'jBCrypt', version: '0.4.1'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.5.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.4'
    compile files("lib/phoenix-client.jar")


}
```

My problem is that the phoenix-client.jar contains Jackson JSON lib dependency with an old version that dosent contain the mapperfeature I need, so are they any way to remove those old jackson lib dependencies from the phoenix-client.jar ? Or any other solution to my problem which is basically convert JSON to POJO and back ?